# How can I use jwt libraries in JMeter to decrypt an encrypted token, which is received from API response in Jmeter 3.0?

Tags: jmeter, performance

How can I use [jwt libraries](https://jwt.io/#libraries-io) in JMeter to decrypt an encrypted token which is received from API response in Jmeter 3.0 script?

Comment: and @Dmitri T, Can you provide me sample code to decode the authentication token in Jmeter using groovy or any other language.

Answer (score 2):

1. Drop the required libraries somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (if you place them in "lib" folder of your JMeter installation it will work)
2. Restart JMeter to pick them up
3. Add [JSR223 Test Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and using [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as a language develop your decryption code
4. ...?
5. Profit

Also consider upgrading to [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) (or whatever is the latest version available at the [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as the most recent JMeter version have bug fixes, performance improvements and new features.